# Convert Table Layout to CSS Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I need some help making this layout work with just `div` and `css`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Side Bar</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Top Menu</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Main Content</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Footer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am thinking something like this:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="main-header"></div>
    <div>
        <div id="side-bar"></div>
        <div>
            <div id="top-nav"></div>
            <div id="main-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-footer"></div>
</div>
```

But I am a little stuck on the CSS.

Comment: I have tried some float=left divs, but then the main content floats and if I clear it it goes below the whole layout.

Comment: You need to post your html & css and take it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        #wrapper {
            width: 80%;
            min-width: 500px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            background: rgb(200,200,200);
        }
        #wrapper header h1 {
            text-align: center;
            background: #BADA55;
        }
        #wrapper nav ul {
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 0;
            text-align: center;
            background: red;
        }
        #wrapper nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 1em 2em;
        }
        #wrapper aside {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            background: blue;
        }
        #main_content {
            float: right;
            width: 70%;
            background: green;
        }
        #wrapper footer {
            clear: both;
            background: black;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Main Header</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="main_content">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <h3>Sidebar</h3>
        <p>Sidebar content</p>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        <p><small>Footer Information</small></p>
    </footer>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

It's divided into colors so that each element is easily visible.

If you have any questions regarding the CSS/HTML, you can ask in the comments and I'll answer.

`div` is a general, completely unsemantic wrapper element. You only use a `<div>` when there's no other element suitable for the job. Which, as you can see here, there are none. All elements are semantic and appropriate.

Comment: I think the CSS is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: "little stuck on the CSS" you need to post ur CSS as well. Meaning the OP

Comment: I have no css yet, well no anything of any use

Comment: @SamStriano: I've updated the answer. Please do check it out.

Comment: Awesome! but what if they target browsers don't support HTML5? Our customers (we are the Oregon State Fund/Workers Comp) are not up to HTML5 browsers yet, some still have IE6 (state agencies).

Comment: @SamStriano: There are ways to counter that. But I can't teach you the whole CSS/HTML5/Polyfilling subject on one question. Please do make some research on your own, and if you have a specific question, do ask here.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Thanks man... I did some research and have it working with some polyfills for IE.